# Embed Google Drive Video files as playlist on iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed, google-drive-api

I have a couple of video files on my google drive and I want to embed these files as a playlist on my site so it plays on one iframe instead of multiple iframes but I can't get a code to do this. I found a similar code for youtube playlist embed but when I tried it with my google embed code it loaded just one file. A copy of the youtube playlist code is below. I'd appreciate it if someone can help with the code/parameter that embeds two or more google drive video into an Iframe as playlist. Gracias

Youtube Playlist Embed Code with multiple videos:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hcdQnK84Pl4?playlist=WnVbH7osG5U,7iw30sK2UCo,sYV5MTy0v1I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```